# The effects of operating a computer with only a keyboard

Tags: computers, ergonomics, repetitive-strain-injury, carpal-tunnel-syndrome

I am wondering what the best method of preventing Repetitive Strain Injury is... A mouse or keyboard.

Specifically, using an application like [Vimac](https://vimacapp.com). With Vimac, you can navigate all the menus with only the keyboard. It can be hard to find computer operations that you *can't* control with a keyboard.

So let's say that you had excellent ergonomics. For example:

- Split keyboard such as the [Freestyle Pro](https://kinesis-ergo.com/shop/freestyle-pro/) (with [accessory](https://kinesis-ergo.com/shop/freestyle-vip3-pro-accessory/) to angle the keyboard to more of a handshake position)
- Ergonomic keyboard layout such as [Dvorak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dvorak_keyboard_layout)
- Proper configurations and usage of shortcuts

Let's also say that we're talking about a typical user that only needs to accomplish basic computer operations. In this case, could a mouse be replaced with a keyboard entirely? Or should a mouse still be used in order to "take a break" from the repetitive task i.e. using the keyboard?

#### Prior research:

[This article](https://techhq.com/2020/05/carpal-tunnel-rsi-repetitive-strain-injury-mouse-computer-alternatives-to-best-2020/) mentions that "[Qutebrowser](https://qutebrowser.org/)" (very similar to Vimac) can be beneficial for Repetitive strain injury, but is more anecdotal and *may* have conflicting interests.

And [NHS.uk](https://www.nhs.uk/live-well/healthy-body/tips-to-prevent-rsi/) mentions:

> Use keyboard shortcuts instead of the mouse to navigate and execute commands.

That's good information and lends to the idea that using a keyboard *more often* is a good idea. However, this doesn't address whether it can be especially harmful to *never* switch input devices.